# How to pass float from shared preferences and add that to the total?

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I am fairly new to android development and i have a dilemma. I want to pass a float from another activity that is in shared preferences and add it to the total.

Basically, what i want to do is:

1. Get the values from Split Activity and pass it to the Main Activity
2. total += passed value
3. display the total
4. save it in shared preferences

And what i have now:

1. Get the values from Split Activity and pass it to the Main Activity
2. it doesn't add in total
3. Displays only the passed value. not the total

I have tried implementing a `float Total = 0;`
then add the passed valued: `Total += passed value` 
But when i display it, it only displays the passed value

All i get is the values are not adding. Which they should. Please enlighten me on this. here are my codes:

Display Bill(Main Activity):

```
    public void DisplayBill(){

    //Retrive Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences Billing = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Bill", MODE_PRIVATE);
    float Total = Billing.getFloat("Bill", 0);

    final TickerView tickerView = (TickerView) findViewById(R.id.ticker_bill);
    tickerView.setCharacterList(TickerUtils.getDefaultNumberList());
    tickerView.setCharacterList(TickerUtils.getDefaultListForUSCurrency());

    tickerView.setText("$".concat(String.valueOf(Total)));
}
```

Split Bill(Split Activity):

```
    public void Compute(){

    //SHARED PREFERENCE
    SharedPreferences Billing = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Bill", MODE_PRIVATE);

    //CES TICKER
    final TickerView tickerCes = (TickerView) findViewById(R.id.tickerCes);
    tickerCes.setCharacterList(TickerUtils.getDefaultNumberList());
    tickerCes.setCharacterList(TickerUtils.getDefaultListForUSCurrency());

    //MON TICKER
    final TickerView tickerMon = (TickerView) findViewById(R.id.tickerMon);
    tickerMon.setCharacterList(TickerUtils.getDefaultNumberList());
    tickerMon.setCharacterList(TickerUtils.getDefaultListForUSCurrency());

    EditText edtBill = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_bill);
    float Bill = Float.parseFloat(edtBill.getText().toString());
    float SplitBill;

    SplitBill = (Bill/2);

    tickerCes.setText("$".concat(String.valueOf(SplitBill)));
    tickerMon.setText("$".concat(String.valueOf(SplitBill)));

    //Set Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Billing.edit();
    editor.putFloat("Bill",Bill);
    editor.commit();

}
```

Comment: have you seen this link?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

Comment: yes. i know how to set and get the values in shared preferences. i will edit my question to be more clear. thanks

Comment: i don't understand have you tried my code??

Comment: yes. it passes fine. but what i want to do is add(plus) it to the running total of the bill. currently with all my codes, i can only display the passed value and I cannot add it to the total. i cannot do total += value

Comment: Declare another variable for that

Comment: i did. i tried total = 0; but whenever it passes, and displays, it just displays the passed values and did not add

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125737/discussion-between-arpit-patel-and-jjcadiz).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way

This might be the problem.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Bill", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

Here is your full method

```
      public void Compute(){

            //SHARED PREFERENCE
            //Retrive Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences Billing = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Bill", MODE_PRIVATE);


            //CES TICKER
            final TickerView tickerCes = (TickerView) findViewById(R.id.tickerCes);
            tickerCes.setCharacterList(TickerUtils.getDefaultNumberList());
            tickerCes.setCharacterList(TickerUtils.getDefaultListForUSCurrency());

            //MON TICKER
            final TickerView tickerMon = (TickerView) findViewById(R.id.tickerMon);
            tickerMon.setCharacterList(TickerUtils.getDefaultNumberList());
            tickerMon.setCharacterList(TickerUtils.getDefaultListForUSCurrency());

            EditText edtBill = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_bill);
            float Bill = Float.parseFloat(edtBill.getText().toString());


            SplitBill = (Bill/2);

 float shared_Total = Billing.getFloat("Bill", 0)+Bill;

            tickerCes.setText("$".concat(String.valueOf(SplitBill)));
            tickerMon.setText("$".concat(String.valueOf(SplitBill)));

            //Set Shared Preferences
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Bill", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putFloat("Bill",shared_Total);
            editor.apply();

        }
```